# Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks

Tags: css, printing, google-chrome

I'm trying to get google chrome to do page breaks.

I've been told via a bunch of websites that `page-break-after: always;` is valid in chrome but I can not seem to get it to work even with a very simple example.   is there any way to force a page break when printing in chrome?

Comment: It appears that this has relatively recently (February 2014) been discussed (on an old 2005 bug ticket) on the webkit bug tracker https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5097

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I've used the following approach successfully in all major browsers including Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Paginated HTML</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
      div.page
      {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <h1>This is Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      <h1>This is Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      <h1>This is Page 3</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a simplified example. In the real code, each page div contains many more elements.

Comment: Ah i see my problem i think.  I was attempting to use it with a <br/> tag

Comment: @Mike Thanks for answering the problem for me. Not sure why a br doesn't work and a div does, but nonetheless an easy change.

Comment: this works when you try to use with parent page, but does not work when you print from iframe (in chrome, of course).

Comment: Also read @peter's answer below; he also had a good point about `position: relative`.

Comment: According to spec `break-after` and `break-before` apply only to `block-level elements, table row groups, table rows (but see prose)`: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-break-3/#break-between – that means no floats or any fancy positioning tricks.

Comment: It do not work if the container uses ```display:flex```

Comment: This worked for me ONLY if the div.page CSS was in an inline style tag with media set to "print".   In other words it does not work inside a @media print element in my global style sheet.

Comment: @Tommyka thanks! This solved my problem. So, in my `@media print {}` I set the `section` to `display:block` instead of `flex`. Took me quite some time to find your hint. !

Comment: That `display: flex` container bug in Chrome should be similar to this Mozilla (Firefox) one: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1622935

Comment: Anyone know why the `page-break-inside: avoid;` line is necessary? I naïvely thought this should work with that line, but I am wrong, and don't understand why.

Answer (score 38):

Actually one detail is missing from the answer that is selected as accepted (from Phil Ross)....

it **DOES** work in Chrome, and the solution is really **silly**!!

Both the parent and the element onto which you want to control page-breaking must be declared as:

```
position: relative
```

check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/petersphilo/QCvA5/5/show/

This is true for:

```
page-break-before
page-break-after
page-break-inside
```

However, controlling page-break-inside in Safari does not work (in 5.1.7, at least)

i hope this helps!!!

PS: The question below brought up that fact that recent versions of Chrome no longer respect this, even with the position: relative;  trick.
However, they do seem to respect:

```
-webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
```

see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/petersphilo/QCvA5/23/show

so i guess we have to add that now...

Hope this helps!

Comment: It depends on the version of WebKit used if it works or not in Chrome. You yourself said it does not work in Safari 5.1.7, so I don't think it's silly at all. The version of WK in what they tested might be different from what you tested.

Comment: That page doesn't work in Chrome 26.0.1410.65, I get 3 pages and the last one only has one word on it). I also tried making sure both the element I want to apply the rule to and its parent have position:relative on my own page, but it still won't add the page break when printing. So is this a feature that comes and goes in Chrome?

Comment: You're right.... it doesn't seem to work in recent versions of chrome; however, you can replace it with: -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid; (see this one: http://jsfiddle.net/QCvA5/22/show/)

Comment: @Peter Any updates here? [I posted an SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535801/page-break-inside-being-ignored) with bounty trying to fix a situation I have using `page-break-inside`. Any help?

Comment: This worked for me with one oddity - it only works if I put the style inline, and not in the seperate css file. I'm using it on an h7 element. Chrome version is 38.0.2125.111 m. `<h7 class="page-breaker" style="display: block;position: relative;page-break-before:always">Grade <?php echo $grade;?></h7>`

Comment: My Bad. Works in css file as well. Had media set to screen when calling the css file.

Answer (score 16):

I just wanted to note here that Chrome also ignores page-break-* css settings in divs that have been floated.

I suspect there is a sound justification for this somewhere in the css spec, but I figured noting it might help someone someday ;-)

Just another note: IE7 can't acknowledge page break settings without an explicit height on the previous block element:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/fe523ec6-2f01-41df-a31d-9ba93f21787b/

Comment: Likely because floating an element takes it out of the document flow in the same way absolutely positioning it does. Elements with position:absolute won't work with page-break-*.

Comment: Also: there shouldn't be any floating or absolute positioned elements among all parents of the element with page break style. I had bootstrap "col-xs-12" parent, when I explicitly set "float: none" to it, the page break began to work!

Answer (score 13):

I had an issue similar to this but I found the solution eventually. I had **overflow-x: hidden;** applied to the <html> tag so no matter what I did below in the DOM, it would never allow page breaks. By reverting to **overflow-x: visible;** it worked fine.

Hopefully this helps somebody out there.

Comment: Note that any parent element with certain overflow properties can cause this issues.  I just added the rule `* { overflow-x: visible }`.

Answer (score 10):

I'm having this problem myself - my page breaks work in every browser but Chrome - and was able to isolate it down to the page-break-after element being inside a table cell. (Old, inherited templates in the CMS.)

Apparently Chrome doesn't honor the page-break-before or page-break-after properties inside table cells, so this modified version of Phil's example puts the second and third headline on the same page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Paginated HTML</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
      div.page
      {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <h1>This is Page 1</h1>
    </div>

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="page">
              <h1>This is Page 2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
              <h1>This is, sadly, still Page 2</h1>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome's implementation is (dubiously) allowed given the CSS specification - you can see more here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=32f9d9629d6f6789&hl=en

Comment: This was my problem - forced into using table cells for layout by SharePoint 2007, so Chrome was obeying any print style sheet layout declarations :(

Answer (score 10):

Beware of CSS : `display:inline-block` when printing.

None of the CCS property to go to next page would work for me in Chrome and Firefox if my table was inside a div with the style `display:inline-block`

For example, the following doesn't work :

```
<div style='display:inline-block'>
  <table style='page-break-before:always'>
    ...
  </table>
  <table style='page-break-before:always'>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

But the following work :

```
<div>
  <table style='page-break-before:always'>
    ...
  </table>
  <table style='page-break-before:always'>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: And "float" as well. There shouldn't be any "float" properties in parent elements.

Comment: Same with `display: flex`

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue on chrome before and the cause for it is that there was a div has min-height set to a value.
The solution was to reset min-height while printing as follows:

```
@media print {
    .wizard-content{
        min-height: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

2016 update:

Well, I got this problem, when I had

```
overflow:hidden
```

on my div.

After I made

```
@media print {
   div {
      overflow:initial !important
   }
}
```

everything became just fine and perfect

Comment: This solved the problem when nothing else did. Thanks!

Comment: That's is a correct option to remember! The content may be just hidden.

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me (2021 Chrome):

```
@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;               // <== this can be missing sometimes
    break-before: always;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you !
What I was missing was the `display: block;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome with Bootstrap Css the classes that control the grid layout eg col-xs-12 etc use "float: left" which, as others have pointed out, wrecks the page breaks. Remove these from your page for printing. It worked for me. (On Chrome version = 49.0.2623.87)

Answer (score 1):

It's now 2021 and this topic is the first result when searching for the exact issue with Chrome.  I found this is a very simple solution that works and can be slapped into your  without any additional effort to at least affect Chrome page breaking in the middle of a :

```
<style>
@media print {
    tr, th, td {
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Hopefully that helps save someone time.

Answer (score 0):

Have that issue. So long time pass...
Without side-fields of page it's break normal, but when fields appears, page and "page break space" will scale. So, with a normal field, within a document, it was shown incorrect. 
I fix it with set

```
    width:100%
```

and use

```
div.page
  {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
```

Use it on first line.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to get the correct page breaks in tables with Google Chrome is giving it to the element `<tr>` the property **display: inline-table** (or display: inline-block but it fits better in other cases that are not tables). Also should be used the properties "page-break-after: always; page-break-inside: avoid;" as written by @Phil Ross

```
<table>
  <tr style="display:inline-table;page-break-after: always; page-break-inside: avoid;">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any hints on getting this to not break the margin/padding inside the tds?

Comment: @joeforker you should use the <tr> with "padding: 0; margin: 0;" and give the margin properties to the elements contained within.

Answer (score 0):

I was printing 16 labels on A4 page landscape rotation, 4 labels per row, page was breaking in the last row and only 12 label were on one page in chrome only,
I was using `display:inline-block;` on a div, then replaced it with `float:right;` and it worked!

Answer (score -2):

It was working for me when I used padding like:

```
<div style="padding-top :200px;page-break-inside:avoid;">
   <div>My content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only worked because of the padding and not because of the page-break