# "page-break-inside: avoid "- does not work

Tags: html, css, printing, reporting, page-break

I am making a print css... And i want to print certain blocks as a whole, therefore I used 'page-break-inside: avoid'. But this doesn't seem to work.

I have been searching desperatly to find a solution... I use Google Chrome

```
    .print-block
    {
        display: block;
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    }
```

This is the CSS, I am using...

Comment: related article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Opera fully supports `page-break-inside`.

References:

[General](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-inside)

[Chrome specific](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=20090828aa91bc90&hl=en)

[Firefox specific](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132035)

Comment: Your link is currently broken, fyi.

Comment: Thank you...
I am solving the problem now by calculating the height of the div's with Javascript and insert an page-break after each 1000px;