# Table breaks when printing

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a site with some tables on it (with thead & tbody).
This site shall be printed with the latest firefox.
Problem: sometimes firefox breaks the page within one of the tables,
the printed version of the site is unusable.
Couldn't find any working solution yet.

Comment: I can quickly think of media="print" stylesheets, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shall fix the problem

```
table { 
   page-break-before: always;
}
```

**Update**::

On that case, use the folloing

```
@media print {
    table {
       page-break-inside:avoid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this i've a new page for each table, where there could be 3-4 tables on one page.

Comment: @iceteea, Actually check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996436/295264) answer. Opera supports page-break-inside more than others does