# How to avoid page break inside tr?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How to avoid page break inside `<tr>`?

(ANGULAR PROJECT) I have table (PrimeNG table) and I want to avoid break after print page.
I use Chromium/Chrome browse. 
After print I have this result:
[image]

So, how to avoid this, or how to disable repeat `thead`?

I tried this links, but dosen't work:

[How to avoid page break inside table row for wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516534/how-to-avoid-page-break-inside-table-row-for-wkhtmltopdf)

["page-break-inside: avoid "- does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996410/page-break-inside-avoid-does-not-work)

[avoid page break inside row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table)

Comment: Hmm do you have a working code snippet? Maybe it is because your font-size is to big...

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem. 
This combination helped me

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: auto;
    }

    body {
        margin: 10mm 15mm 10mm 15mm; /* margin you want for the content */
    }

    p, img, a, div.image, div{
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    table, thead, tbody, tr, td, th, label, strong{
        page-break-inside: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add `@page {size: A4;}`

Answer (score 0):

The following is what worked in Chrome to:

1. Prevent table cell contents from being split across a page break.
2. Prevent table rows from having arbitrary vertical gaps between them a few rows after each page break.

```css
@media print {
  tr, td {
    break-after: auto;
    break-inside: auto;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}
```