# break-inside: avoid doesn't work for basic example

Tags: html, css

I'm using Chrome v99 and a pretty basic usage of `break-inside: avoid` - but it does nothing.

**Moderator**: This is not a duplicate of [this post and the 1 answer there isn't helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996410/page-break-inside-avoid-does-not-work).

My objective is to disallow the contents of all these divs from splitting at page breaks:

```
<div class="opt">
```

Here is my inline css:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    @media print {
        div.opt, table {
            break-inside: avoid !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

The full html is a bit lengthy but you can view the entirety [here](https://instant-rsvp.com/temp/QuickView-SO.html).

Simply press `CTRL+P` and observe that it page-breaks in the middle of `div`s with a class of `opt` - but it shouldn't because I'm using `break-inside: avoid`.

The example I linked to is very short and contrived, but my real scenario has many more sections and is dynamic, pulling from a database. So there's no way to know where the page is going to break relative to the divs. I just want the contents within those divs with that class to always stay together on the same page and never split across a page break. No div contents ever exceed a page, they are even shorter than my example.

Help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have media=screen in the style tag...
Your print styles will only load when you're using a screen and not a printer

```css
<style media="print" type="text/css">
  div.opt, table {
    break-inside: avoid !important;
  }
</style>
```

When you fix it though it still seems to wrap onto multiple pages uglier but at least now you can play around with what print styles work