# Should CSS "orphan" operate at line or block level?

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

I'm rendering HTML documents to PDF. Previously I was using [Wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), but it looks like [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) offers better support for page breaks, so I expect I will switch to that.

I'd like to apply some orphan control to my document, so I need to have a solid understanding of what `orphans` actually does. From W3C ([source](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/orphans)):

> The orphans property specifies the minimum number of lines in a block container that must be left at the bottom of a page.

The example that is consistently offered around the web is this:

```
p { orphans: 3; }
```

This means that if there isn't space for three lines of paragraph text, a break is forced to the next page. I am rendering a document containing a lot of unordered lists, so for me it would be:

```
li { orphans: 2; }
```

However, I'd also ideally like to break an unordered list so that a bullet item block is not orphaned or widowed on its own. It would be nice to be able to do this:

```
ul { orphans: 2; }
```

That would ideally ensure that no item block could appear above or below a page break on its own. However browser/renderer support for this is patchy, and W3C above use the word "line" rather than "block". Thus, I imagine the above would just affect paragraph line control within list items, and would not affect whole list item blocks. If that is the case, is there a CSS way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you would want a page break before a `li` element if only one `li` element would otherwise fit on a page (no matter how many lines there are in the content)? If not, what then? In any case, the `orphans` property always relates to lines.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what `orphans` should do. Yes indeed: if there are four `li` items, and there's space for three of them at the end of a page, then the break should go between the second and third. This would be where we have a property value of 2 (i.e. the minimum number of blocks). This issue isn't critical for me, but I thought it would be interest to explore generally. I wonder whether it would need JavaScript to implement (which would be possible in Prince and wkhtmltopdf, but not dompdf).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by liZe on the [WeasyPrint issue tracker](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/503):

> Orphans / Widows only work for line-boxes, not for block-like boxes.
>
> Fortunately, you can define rules like:
>
> ```
> li:last-child {
>   break-before: avoid;
> }
> li:first-child {
>   break-after: avoid;
> }
> ```