# Orphan CSS: How avoid headers (h1, h2...) on bottom page?

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

I have a large HTML document with headers (h1, h2, h3...) and paragraphs. When I print the document, I want that, automatically, headers at bottom of document go to next page:

[image]

How can I do? I use "orphans: 3" CSS with paragraphs and works with "p" tags, but with h1 or h2 don't work.

```
@page {
  size: A4;
}

p {
  orphans:3;
}

h1, h2 {
  orphans:3
}
```

[Full example on action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwrwOY) where:

- 1-2 page: paragraphs orphan works fine.
- 2-3 page: headers don't works.

Requirements:

- HTML have one main div container.
- **Don't alter HTML**.
- Browser support isn't important (on my specific job).
- I need some trick in CSS (no JS or Jquery, preferably)
- I can't use page-break-before:always because I want that headers only go to next page when appears at bottom of page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Too much theory.. can we get some code in action?

Comment: You should be aware, that print-specific styles such as `orphans`, `break-after` etc. have notoriously bad support by browsers, so there will always be cases where these things don't work. Generally printing and page based styles are still a weak point for HTML/CSS, so if you need good quality print-outs, you seriously should look at alternatives such as PDF.

Comment: @RoToRa for me, browser support isn't important. I want translate information to PDF without manual layout tasks. With one support-browser is enough.

Answer (score 15):

In typography an orphan is:

> A paragraph-opening line that appears by itself at the bottom of a page or column, thus separated from the rest of the text.

However in HTML `<h1>` and `<p>` are different *paragraphs* then what you have to use is `break-after` property to tell layout engine to do not put a page break after that paragraph (with the side effect to move next paragraph up to previous page - if fit - or to move header to next page.

```
h1, h2 {
    break-after: avoid-page;
}
```

Note about compatibility: `break-after` setting is a *true* working draft and even basic features are not widely supported (notably Internet Explorer 10 **does**). To workaround this you may use another property with similar meaning:

```
h1, h2 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

Note that `page-break-after` applies to both page and columns. `page-break-after` isn't well supported by FF ([it is a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132035)) then if compatibility is important and paragraph won't span across multiple pages you can workaround wrapping `<h1>` and `<p>` inside a container (let's say `<section>`) and then apply `page-break-inside` like this:

```
section {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

IMO you should combine `page-break-after` and `page-break-inside` using `page-break-inside` with `-moz` prefix until it will fix that bug.

Comment: Your answer is perfect, I understand and know this points, but the theory don't work (or I do some incorrect). Could give some code (or modify codepen example for "Select all text" / Print) and show how works? In my example, I don't get "Blah blah" header go to next page.

Comment: Don't try inside CodePen, using a standalone file it works. Of course browser compatibility is aleatory (at best, typography isn't so well supported). Most _compatible_ way is last described one, it slightly change how output is rendered (because it'll try to keep all section together, possibly even without breaking paragraphs and adding - when required - a page break before first title). With this difference it's only one I saw rendered correctly in every browser I tried.

Comment: does it work for any one? i tried but not worked for me? any suggestions?

Comment: @macha it depends on the browser, second one compatibility is good but you definitely should try. Which browser? What's the exact code?

Comment: currently i am using chrome latest version @Adriano Repetti

Comment: What's the code? 2 years ago chrome worked pretty well with last snippet

Comment: Please  add      https before url

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of this older one: [How do I avoid a page break immediately after a heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238868/how-do-i-avoid-a-page-break-immediately-after-a-heading)

The best working solution is code like this:

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
  break-inside: avoid;
}
h1::after, h2::after, h3::after, h4::after, h5::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```