# Rendertron modifying CSS

Tags: phantomjs, server-side-rendering, rendertron

Rendertron is loading my webpage, but it is prefacing the CSS file (bundled app.css via webpack) with the following PRE tag and HTML tags:

```
<html><head><base href="https://redacted-for-security.com/css"></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">@font-face{font-family:swiper-icons;font-style:normal;font </pre></body></html>
```

This obviously breaks the page layout for the render.

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: To be clear, this is added to the app.css file

Comment: Are you running Rendertron locally?

Comment: I believe its trying to show css used on the page, for a quick fix to hide pre-tag using body pre:first-child {display: none} or using appropriate css selectors.

Comment: @Joel Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `<head>`.

The CSS property [`page-break-after: avoid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Paged_Media) doesn't work in any [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5097) or [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132035) based browsers, so you can alternatively use the [`page-break-inside: avoid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Paged_Media) over the heading and an acceptable amount of the text to prevent this page break:

#### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .nobreak {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
</style>
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="nobreak">
    <h3>Heading!</h3>
    
    <p>Some things:</p>
        
</div>

    <ul>
      <li>Thing one</li>
      <li>Thing B</li>
      <li>Thing 4</li>
    </ul>
```

Relvant sources:

- [How do I avoid a page break immediately after a heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238868/how-do-i-avoid-a-page-break-immediately-after-a-heading/)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how this is relevant to the question, could you please explain?