# How can I specify page breaks in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, page-break

I want to add page breaks to my site so that other elements will not be cut in half when a user tries to print the page. I've tried adding the css "page-break-after: always", but it only works on Firefox, and can't find any other solutions.

There are a couple similar questions (one here: [Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)) but they're very old (2009) and the solution no longer works.

Does anyone know of a way to do this with current versions of Safari and Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue similar to this but I found the solution eventually. I had overflow-x: hidden; applied to the  tag so no matter what I did below in the DOM, it would never allow page breaks. By reverting to overflow-x: visible; it worked fine.

Hopefully this helps somebody out there.