# How to achieve page break in HTML table for Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to print a large table generated with jQuery in an HTML page. I am using Chrome 26.0.141. The issue is with page break.

i initially used this css

```
#membersList table { page-break-inside:auto; position:relative}
#membersList tr { page-break-before:avoid; page-break-after:auto;position:relative}
#membersList td{ border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;width:auto;position:relative}
#membersList thead { display:table-header-group;position:relative }
#membersList tfoot { display:table-footer-group;positioion:relative}
```

this dint worked so i searched and got this link
[Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)

based on one of the answer in that link i am using the following CSS attribute

```
 -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
```

But when I run and inspect the element, it is stroked out by default.

What would be the solution? There are lot of posts I searched. They say that recent versions don't support page break. If it's true then what other solution is there to achieve page break in Google Chrome?

Comment: if you can post an example using www.jsbin.com it will help anyone coming up with a suggestion.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui did you checked my previous code. i tried what you have described but  that dint worked for me. please check my code and tell me if anything is wrong with that.

Comment: Finally i resolved this issue. I made`     tr{display:block;}` and then i fixed the the cell spacing. page break only works on block level elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue. I made `tr{display:block;}`
and then I fixed the cell spacing.

Page break only works on block level elements.

Comment: How did you fix the cell spacing?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to split the table into several parts, and set their `page-break-after` css property to `always`. This works (with beta Chrome), I don't know if there is a way to do it in a continuous table.

Comment: i am generating the table dynamically so splitting is not possible.

Comment: Can't you insert a split every x rows? Server or client side? With some CSS trickery, there might be no visible difference.

Comment: i m not sure about the row content because few row may contain more data than other. all the rows are not even in size thats the problem.

Comment: You might still get better results by making a guess.

Comment: Finally i resolved this issue. I madetr{display:block;} and then i fixed the the cell spacing. page break only works on block level elements.

Comment: How did you fix the cell spacing?

Answer (score 2):

As said on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after):

> WebKit browsers doesn't support this property; but some have the
>   non-standard -webkit-column-break-after and -webkit-region-break-after
>   with similar parameters as page-break-after.

So you need to use **`page-break-after`** with some value which suits you the best. Here are some of them:

> The page-break-after CSS property adjusts page breaks after the
>   current element.

**auto:**
Initial value. Automatic page breaks (neither forced nor forbidden).

**always:**
Always force page breaks after the element.

**avoid:**
Avoid page breaks after the element.

**left:**
Force page breaks after the element so that the next page is formatted as a left page.

**right:**
Force page breaks after the element so that the next page is formatted as a right page.

You can also use the **`break-after`** property:

> The break-after CSS property describes how the page, column or region
>   break behavior after the generated box. If there is no generated box,
>   the property is ignored.

Comment: did you checked my previous code. i tried what you have described but that dint worked for me. please check my code and tell me if anything is wrong with that.

Comment: Finally i resolved this issue. I made`    tr{display:block;}    ` and then i fixed the the cell spacing. page break only works on block level elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have provided a few patches to qt to improve table page breaks. You may wish to check out issue 168 http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=168#c13

Comment: i am a newbie this sounds greek and latin. could you please explain it simply.

Comment: Finally i resolved this issue. I made `     tr{display:block;}     ` and then i fixed the the cell spacing. page break only works on block level elements.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like several tables to make this thing happen as @sabof mentioned. Say I wanted 11 rows should come on the page.

```
<table>
   11 * <tr></tr>
</table>
<table>
   11 * <tr></tr>
</table>
```

HTML markups;

```
<div id="printSection">
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I created rows dynamically so the JQuery logic were the following;

```
var j = 23;

for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {

    if (i != 0 && i % 11 == 0) {

         $("#printSection div").append("<table><tbody></tbody></table>");              
   }              

   var node = "<tr><td>Your Data</td></tr>";
   $("#printSection tbody").last().append(node);
   }
}
```

CSS were something like this;

```
#printSection table {            
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome (2022):

```
tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

It will prevent a table row from being split in a page break.