# page break css after every second <tr> not working in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, print-css

i have dynamic items in `tr` , try to pint two `tr` per page and my css is

**CSS :**

```
 @media print {
      body {font-size:10px}
       table tr:nth-child(2n) {
        page-break-after: always;
        }
        .noptrint {display:none;}
      }
```

and see http://jsfiddle.net/4jr8s/

it work on `firefox` but not in `Chrome` browser, what is problem in `chrome` ?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/1647062/2567813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to achieve page break in HTML table for Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761646/how-to-achieve-page-break-in-html-table-for-google-chrome)

Finally i resolved this issue. I madetr{display:block;} and then i fixed the the cell spacing. page break only works on block level elements. @sarsarahman

Comment: was tr {display: block; } the only thing you did to get it working(and page-break-inside: avoid; of cause? I have the same issue but this does not seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make all `<tr>` as `{display: block}` and then where you want page break, you can do `{page-break-after: always}`.