# Page breaks in a table

Tags: html, css, printing, webkit

I'm trying to make reports in HTML, everything is working ok except one thing. I have a few delivery locations which are grouped. Imagine a group of addresses in a certain ZIP-code area. 
These groups may not exceed the page, but to minimize paper waste I want to add more of these groups on the page.
I'm using WKHTMLtoPDF to create a PDF file and everything looks great except when I try to force a page break. I have used a number of suggested options like

```
<tr class="pageBreak" style="display: block;"></tr>
<tr style="display: block;"><td colspan="10"><p class="pageBreak">&nbsp;</p></tr>
```

With:

```
page-break-after: always !important;
```

But every try i get a very large cell on the next page [See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Frt.jpg)

I can't find out how this is happening and how to prevent this from happening. I've already set the height of the row to 1px and that also doesn't help. (My HTML is valid)

I know that webkit is (a bit) buggy with tables but this is the last thing I need to figure out to make this work.

**Update**
I found someone who has (i think) the same issue so I think can't continue. Are there other good html2pdf converters out there? https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1640

Yours sincerely,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue long back and i dint knew what is the solution to come over it here is my question... and check out my answer below the question. [How to achieve page break in HTML table for Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761646/how-to-achieve-page-break-in-html-table-for-google-chrome)

Comment: I've already tried the solution you provided. After trying to print in chrome the page breaks are working correctly. I think this is a bug in WKHTMLtoPDF. The page layout looks totally different in pdf then it does when printed with chrome.