# Page break in DataList (asp.net) in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, page-break

I have created a Page with the **Datalist** control in it, which generates "ID cards".
You can see the working example [here](http://rajseva.com/EmployeeTest.aspx).

The problem is that I want to break the page after every *4th* row of **Datalist**.

So to execute this, I am using this **jQuery** code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#GridView1 tr:nth-child(4n+0)").addClass("breakpage");

        })
    </script>
```

And the **CSS** class:

```
<style type="text/css">
                .breakpage {
                page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
```

So if you open the page and check with the inspect element, you can see that the **jQuery** is working, and it does add the class on every *4th* row.
But still, when I try to take a print, **the page break is not working in Google Chrome (working fine in firefox)**.

> Could someone please explain what is wrong with the code?

Thank you.

Comment: Your website link does not seem to do anything, the page remains empty

Comment: I am sorry, I have corrected the link, please try now. Thank you

Comment: Can't you use margin or padding? Is there any specific reason to do so?

Comment: @ygssoni your jquery for adding the breakpage class is not working entirely I think, it's also putting it on every 4th tr _inside_ your cards (this line: "कर्मचारी आईडीः 123456789" for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to achieve page break in HTML table for Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761646/how-to-achieve-page-break-in-html-table-for-google-chrome) can you see if this page helps? It might have something to do with a `tr` being `display: table-row` instead of `display: block`
Apparently Chrome only applies the page break to block level elements.

Edit: I've just tested that setting the following fixes it:

```
#GridView1 > tbody > tr {
    display: block;
}
```

[image: pagebreak after every 4th tr]

If I shrunk the margins of the pages the pagebreak didn't fall on the next page, but playing around with the sizes of your cards would fix this too so you don't have a fully empty page

Answer (score 1):

Try it in CSS with this:

```
#GridView1 tr:nth-of-type(4n) {
  page-break-after:always;
}
```

Comment: thank you. but this too is working fine on firefox, but not in Chrome. I am searching a solution for google chrome.

Comment: Did you remove the jQuery?

Comment: this solutions may help [Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)