# Page-Break-inside property is not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, page-break-inside

I have a long table data, which having many of the rows and nested tables. When I am printing this data then the rows of the table and nested tables are just break on the page break, means tables and data are split into pages, So I use following CSS property there:-

```
table tr {
 page-break-inside:avoid;
 position:relative;
 }
```

But this is not working in my case, you can see the live demo here:--http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/S8vr8/2/show/

Please edit the code by following link:--
http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/S8vr8/2/

---[For Print the page just press [CTRL+P] or right click and click on Print option]---

I am using Google Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m

Please let me know where the problem exactly.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks

Comment: I already done these all things already, I read so many posts on stack overflow, but nothing will work me in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of putting the `page-break-inside:avoid;` on you table's tr, try applying it on the table directly like this:

```
table {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    position:relative;
}
```

also add this media query:

```
@media print {
   table {
        page-break-inside:avoid;
        position:relative;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me it turned out to be the body css:

```
body{
    height: auto!important;
    float: none!important;
}
```