# page-break/webkit-region-break not working in chrome anymore?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I'm trying to make Chrome work with page-break for printing. I've found multiple topics here, and tried a lot of possible solutions, but non of them worked for me.

The topic's i've tried:

[Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks), 
[Page-Break-inside property is not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860923/page-break-inside-property-is-not-working-in-chrome), [CSS Page-Break Not Working in all Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884380/css-page-break-not-working-in-all-browsers)

And more..

I've created a jsfiddle to show what i've got for code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bLezsLkr/1/

(can't post without code: CSS which is used)

```
@media print {
.pageBreak {
    page-break-after: always;
    -webkit-region-break-after: always;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

.topinfo {
    -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-region-break-after: always;
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.blockTitle {
    page-break-after: avoid;
    -webkit-region-break-after: avoid;
}

.leftPix, img {
    -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside : avoid;
}
}
```

### Question:

Why does Internet Explorer print the page as i want, and why does Chrome print the page with the second row of colored blocks on 2 pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the element with `page-break-after: always;` is a block element. Another selector might be changing it to inline-block or something else which would prevent the break from being applied.

Also make sure the element is not within a `float`ed element. Thanks RoadBump.

Comment: Thank you. Because of your answer i checked the parent blocks and it seemed the parent block was a inline-block. After changing it into a block, all worked fine.

Thank you!

Comment: In addition, make sure that it or one of its parents are not `float`ed. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works in chrome

```
 <p style="page-break-before: always">
```