# Chrome doesn't recognize "break-after: avoid"

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium, page-break

I am using Windows 10 with Chrome 79.0.3945.130. I have HTML documents that contain `<h3>` tags. When printing, I would like to avoid page breaks immediately after these tags.

The natural way to prevent page breaks seems to be to use the CSS `break–after` property. And I find that it works in Microsoft Edge. But I can't get it to work in Chrome or in the current, Chromium-based version of Edge. Here is a minimal example:

```html
<html>

  <head><title>Getting CSS page breaks to work</title></head>

  <body>

    <style>
      h3 { break-after: avoid; }
      .tall { 
        height: 9.5in;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="tall"></div>

    <h3>Section heading</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I print that document in an old version of Edge (~v44), it prints as it should. But when I print it in Chrome or the current version of Edgs (v83), the `<h3>` header appears at the bottom of the page, and the following `<p>` text appears at the top of the following page. Breaking the page between `<h3>` and `<p>` is what I want to prevent.

I can get around the problem by wrapping both the `<h3>` and the `<p>` tag in a div and setting `break–inside: avoid` for that div. But this solution is unsatisfactory: it is ad hoc, requiring me to first identify all of the cases in which inappropriate breaks appear.

I have tried many variations on the example given here. For example, I've tried setting the break-* properties in conjunction with the `::after` selector, as in `h3::after { break-after: avoid; }`. But I haven't succeeded in preventing page breaks.

There are also some related posts, for example:

1. [CSS Printing: Avoiding cut-in-half DIVs between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/907680/697473)
2. [page-break/webkit-region-break not working in chrome anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29102821/697473))

but the advice given there doesn't help with the example given above.

What else can I do?

Comment: Looks like Chrome has not yet implemented the `break-*` handling, based on information [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5630943616303104). Not sure if making the `<h3>` element `float:left` might help with the goal?

Comment: Thank you, @PaulT. Adding `float:left` doesn't help, but the Chrome Platform Status note to which you linked is helpful. What a shame that Chrome doesn't have good support for the `avoid` value.

Comment: Other CSS styling may be needed, besides float, but I'm not sure what. That was simply the first style considered.

Comment: More detail on the Chromium/Chrome/Edge bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223068. Apparently, the Chromium developers are working on it...but it sounds as though it'll take a while to fix.

Comment: This is the best solution I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742871/1927583