# Page-break-inside for table does not work in Chrome 50

Tags: css

I've seen this question all around, but nothing worked for me. Most of the topics are quite old, so I guess it has to do with the Chrome version. (Chrome 50)

I have a simple table

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
  ...
  <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
</table>
```

As suggested, I tried adding

```
table {
  position:relative;
  page-break-inside: auto;
}
```

and

```
tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67uma9ea/).

The print page does not look as I'd like it to, the page breaks inside a row.

Also, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860923/page-break-inside-property-is-not-working-in-chrome) I tried setting

```
 table {
   page-break-inside: avoid;
 }
```

But this did not work as well.
This is how it looks[image]
I'd want to find a way such that the page break wouldn't 'cut' a row.

Comment: Try wrapping your text inside a `p` tag.

Comment: Can you edit the fiddle?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you can change that by changing print settings on Chrome. Or you can set format size to A4 on CSS. See an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size