# 'page-break-after: always ' is not working on ie11

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have basic html code which has some tables in it. I have used `page-break-after: always` to differentiate two div's . When I print this page from `chrome` and `Firefox` browser, both div's are getting displayed in separate pages for example div1 gets displayed in page1 and div2 gets displayed in page2 which is correct. But problem is in `IE11` where both the div's are getting displayed on same page . i.e div1 and div2 are displaying on page1.

I am attaching screenshot for chrome and firefox [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD4se.png) 
And IE 11 screenshot [IE11 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYoPH.png)

Can anyone help me to show both div's on separate pages in IE11 also. thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the page-break rule set in a class or as inline styling? I remember reading somewhere that IE9/10/11 ignore this rule if set as inline.

Comment: I have added separate class  here is my css <style type="text/css" media="print">.page-break {
 page-break-after: always !important; padding-top:1cm !important;
}
</style>

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also read [ask] one more time, as you now for a second time posting the same question again, lacking the same info you were told earlier.

Comment: Did you read this question too? Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071786/br-style-page-break-after-always-not-working-windows-8-8-1

Comment: @LGSon , what more information do you need?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv , yes i have seen this , but that didn't help

Comment: SO guide lines clearly state _"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"_ and your's fail at _"shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"_ ... you've missed that or simply decided to leave it out.