# page-break-after not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit

Printing with page-break-after:always does not seem to work in Chrome.  The example below works in IE 11 and FireFox but not in Chrome. How can I make this work in Chrome?

See this example:
http://jsbin.com/iGEyUXi/1

Code here
http://jsbin.com/iGEyUXi/1/edit

**EDIT:**
This applies to when trying to page-break inside an html table

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)

Comment: Does not seem to work
http://jsbin.com/oVamata/1/edit