# Consisting font size for printing a div

Tags: jquery, css

i am printing a div using jquery Plugin PrintThis But unfortunately its printing all the text in different size by different browser, Google Chrome is printing one page on two pages while firefox and internet explorer both are printing the same on a single page. How i can control it. I think it can be controlled using css Font-Size. I am using font size in pixel form. (font-size: 12px)
And Another main issue which i am facing is that i am using "page-break-before: always" for breaking page it is working fine in IE and FireFox but not working with Chrome

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks

Comment: Some questions that will help us solve this faster...
1. When you print them out are the font-sizes themselves different... or is it just everything else (margins, page breaks, etc) that is different?
2. Have you definitely tried using "font-size: 12px;" CSS? You sounded unsure so I'm curious.
3. What version of IE, Firefox, and Chrome are you testing this on? Different version have different levels of compatibility with page-break-before css.

Comment: Actually i am printing a div having Form in which i am having table, Paragraphs rest of the things are fine only font size is different especially while printing, I am using inline Style sheet and IE version is 8, Chroome - 32.0 and FireFox - 26. Actually i searched on the net it was mentioned to use pt / em instead of px, But i am not sure its possible or not

Comment: You didn't answer the question if you checked that the page margins are the same in the different browsers. Also, as you are using tables, are you using quirks mode? In quirks mode, font sizes don't inherit into tables.

Comment: No i checked the page margins are different not same in all the three browsers. Yes i am using quirks mode

Comment: @Ricky then make sure the tables have `font-size:12px` as well! Or, better, use standards compliance mode, since different browsers have different quirks.