# php code to break page after every nth iteration

Tags: php

I am printing barcode on a page...from database...

**I need to display only 6 barcode coupon on single page.**

**After that I need to break page**.....and continue...till last row.

below is my code...but i cannot understand how to count and break page after every 6th row.

plz help me..

```
<?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>

<table  border="1px solid #666" summary="" width="48%" class="pos_fixed1">
<thead>

<tr>
<td>Receipt</td>
<td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['receipt_no']); ?></td>

<td>Coupon</td>
<td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['coupon']); ?></td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: take a look at "php pagination tutorial" in g? ;)

Comment: check mysql queries with limit record and php tutorial for pagination

Comment: can is it possible to count loop increment and when count = 6 then add page break......

Comment: i also try this with pagination...but in pagination you need to button to move on to next page...and i dont need to show button......bcoz this is print report.....

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments, a good way around your problem would be to use pagination, as it means that you are giving users a way to still see this information. For quite a basic tutorial on this, I suggest looking [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928).

Alternatively, if you really need to use the approach you mentioned then something below may help you:

```
$count = count($data); //size of your array
$curr_count = 0; //will be used to increment each turn of loop
$show = 6; //how many pieces of data you want to show
foreach($data as $row) {
  $curr_count++;
  if($curr_count <= $show) {
    //show first 6 pieces of data
  } else if ($curr_count == $count) {
    //show last data
  } else {
    //do your page break
  }
}
```

Comment: your code is correct ..but there is something wrong on that...i need when counter...reaches to 6....then do page break and restart counting again.......but your code only display 6 barcode on single page..and rest values are not displaying....on another page....

Comment: i need after   if($curr_count <= $show) {  //this line of code need else condition of page break and need to restart loop counting again from 1..
    //show first 6 pieces of data
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
 P.breakhere {page-break-before: always}
 .tblBRCD{border="1px solid #666" summary="" width="48%"}
</STYLE> 
<table   class="pos_fixed1 tblBRCD">
<?php 
$count==0;
foreach($data as $row)
{
 echo '<tr><td>Receipt</td><td>'. htmlspecialchars($row['receipt_no']) .'</td>
<td>Coupon</td><td>'. htmlspecialchars($row['coupon']) .'</td></tr>';
$count++;
if($count==6){echo '<P CLASS="breakhere">'; $count=0;}
}
?>
</table>
```

see this [article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470341/CSS-and-Printing.htm%20'article') for further reference

Comment: see this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)