# Copying HTML to word with chrome doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Here is my problem: I generate some html with tables and images, then a user copies the whole web page and pasts it into word. It all works fine just the page breaks are no longer working/being copied from chrome 50.0.2661.94, I tried the same in firefox and it works fine.

Just a fast example

```
<h1>Page1</h1>
<br clear="all" style="mso-special-character:line-break;">
<h2>Page2</h2>
```

[Example](http://output.jsbin.com/bavupejufi)

When pasting the whole html from firefox it works fine, but chrome just pasts it without the page breaks.

Using this for page breaks in word
[link](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation#page_break)

Comment: Chrome probably ignores (and actively removes) that style.

Comment: You have to use it with DIV tag, not BR tag as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks

Comment: (I'm using chromium and it works)