# How to insert a page break in HTML so wkhtmltopdf parses it?

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

So basically I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert a dynamic HTML report to PDF.

The report has a particular format and I've been asked to clone that format with HTML.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't simulate a 100% functional page break in html so wkhtmltopdf can interpret it and send content to another page.

I'm trying to avoid page size measurement methods and so.

TIA for any help provided.

EDIT:
So far I'm emulating page break using `<br>` and it works. I still have to do some testing though.

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` should respect CSS [@media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)  rules

Comment: Ok this is something to start with. I'll try and find out more about those rules. TY

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Specify a CSS rule specific to the print media type. There are [a number of properties that can be used for paging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media). I find it easiest to attach the `page-break-before` property to a class, as shown below.

In the HTML:

```
<p>Page 1, paragraph 1</p>
<p class="new-page">Page 2, paragraph 1</p>
<p>Page 2, paragraph 2</p>
```

In the CSS:

```
@media print {
  .new-page {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I've solved this like a monkey adding <br> and trying until I like it, this is a really useful approach to what I've been asking for and I appreciate a lot.

Comment: You'll probably also need to specify the `--print-media-type` argument for it to obey `@media print`.

Comment: I removed the `@media print {` as I was using serverside rendering.

Comment: I am getting a blank first page when I do this method. It works mostly, except the first page is blank. I'm using Pandoc to convert MD to HTML then wkhtmltopdf as the pdf-engine.

Comment: @FilBot3 Assuming you have not added the `new-page` class to the first page, inspect the CSS to see if it has a page break before the content begins. That might help trace where it is coming from.

Comment: I think what my problem was is that I was using Pandoc to run wkhtmltopdf to make the PDF. It would continually add a blank page between the cover and the frist page, or with no cover, just a blank page.

Answer (score 119):

When I use `wkhtmltopdf`, I work with the following classes:

```
.keep-together {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.break-before {
    page-break-before: always;
}

.break-after {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

So I can force:

- That a particular container content is not spread over two pages (if it fits one page). When using the `keep-together` class a page break is created before the container if necessary.
- That a page break is forced before a particular container.
- That a page break is forced after a particular container.

The `@media print` didn't work for me with `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: `@media print` didn't work for me either. Thanks, this helped.

Comment: @Surya Did you remember to add the `--print-media-type` argument when calling wkhtmltopdf, eg `wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type myPage.html myPage.pdf` ?

Comment: @JamesDaily - I don't remember if I did. I'll give it a try. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: This still wasn't working for me, but it turned out to be because I had `overflow-x: hidden` set on the `html` and `body` tag.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9670743/2223706).

Comment: I was running into the same issue until I followed your advice of adding `--print-media-type` to the command line. Thank you

Answer (score 66):

```
<div style = "display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;"></div>
```

Just add that in your html code

Comment: This is the real one!! Without running with any arguments, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

@media print worked for me with wkhtmltopdf when I used the option --print-media-type for wkhtmltopdf

Comment: to complete this answer, you also need to deal with html page break as described here https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/html+page+break

Answer (score 0):

people having this issue, try downgrading wkhtmltopdf to version 0.10.0 rc2, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

When using `wkhtmltopdf` as the pdf engine for `pandoc`, the order of passing options to `wkhtmltopdf` mattered.

For example, **this did not work**, because `--pdf-engine-opt=toc` came before `--pdf-engine-opt=--print-media-type`:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine-opt=toc --pdf-engine-opt=--print-media-type --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf -o out.pdf out.md
```

Switching them around did work:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine-opt=--print-media-type --pdf-engine-opt=toc --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf -o out.pdf out.md
```