# How can I enable PDF page breaks from HTML, maybe using a marker in the source HTML file?

Tags: python, html, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit to create a PDF from a HTML file... like so:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file([source], target + '.pdf')
```

I create the HTML file myself before doing this conversion.
What I'm now trying to do is find a way to impleet a page break.
The HTML file doesn't use page breaks because ... well, it's basic html.
But PDF's are page type structures.

So how can I pickup something in the HTML as a marker, and then use that to implement a page break  in the PDF?

Of course `pdfkit.from_file([source], target + '.pdf')` is a simple single line... there's no parsing of the content..... so I don't see how I could tell it what to look for.

Any ideas?

EDIT
With some advice from @Nathanial below, I've added to my CSS

```
@media print {
  h2 { 
    page-break-before: always;
  }
```

But I don't see `pdfkit.from_file([source], target + '.pdf')` picking it up?

Opening the html file in the browser and printing to PDF works perfectly. so this is more of a pdfkit issue.

Found a similar question here:
[How to insert a page break in HTML so wkhtmltopdf parses it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005819/how-to-insert-a-page-break-in-html-so-wkhtmltopdf-parses-it)

I think the pdfkit wrapper for wkhtmltopdf is limited.
On the commnd line, this works perfectly.

```
wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type 10100005.html 10100005.pdf
```

But how do I replicate that in python? It's not my first choice to doa `os.execute`....:/

Comment: Use media print and print only styles. Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463796/how-to-only-show-certain-parts-with-css-for-print

Comment: You mean this sort of thing? 

@media print {
  footer {page-break-after: always;}
}

Comment: Yes and even print specific classes; you could add in separators/page breaks that are .print-only for example.

Comment: OK... but I'm not sure that `pdfkit.from_file([source], target + '.pdf')` picks that up?

Comment: If you're printing the html document and the css is applied then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling, this worked for me. I'm putting this here to help the next person.

Thanks @Nathaniel Flick for pointing me to use media print and print only styles.

Example 11 on this page also helped
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/100586/pdfkit.from_file

In the style sheet

```
@media print {
  h2 { 
    page-break-before: always;
     }
      }
```

Then in the python code

```
pdfkit_options = {
   'print-media-type': '',
}


>>> print (source)
c:/users/maxcot/desktop/Reports/10100001.html

>>> print (target)
c:/users/maxcot/desktop/Reports/10100001.pdf

>>> print (pdfkit_options)
{'print-media-type': ''}

pdfkit.from_file(source, target, options=pdfkit_options)
```