# css page break not working in latest version of Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, google-chrome

Chrome updated to a new version recently (Version 58.0.3029.96) and now my page break has stopped working. I'm using a `div` for the page break:

```
<div id="pagebreakGrid" class="pagebreak" runat="server" visible="false"></div>
```

Then is css I had:

```
.pagebreak  { 
        page-break-after: always;   
    }
```

I also tried changing the css to this but it didn't fix it:

```
.pagebreak  { 
        display: block;
        page-break-after: always;
        position: relative;       
    }
```

This code used to work fine and still works in Internet Explorer. Does anyone know how to get page breaks to work in the new version of Chrome?

Comment: Before using page-break-after, check if you can use break-after instead. In the future page-break-after will be a mere alias for some values of it.

Comment: Have you tried using `break-after: page` - I think the `page-break-after` is being replaced by break after: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: @HassanImam I tried using `break-after` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Pete I replaced `page-break-after` with `break-after` but it didn't change anything

Comment: By the looks of things there is no support for either of them

Comment: @user123456789 Can you use following css `{
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }` and see if it is working or not.
Source: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)

Comment: @user123456789 You can use this one too. `-webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;`

Comment: @HassanImam `page-break-inside` or `-webkit` didn't work either

Comment: @Pete do you know if there is another way of doing page breaks?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any other way - I've never bothered with it as it never worked properly