# How can I avoid table to break in print preview?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, page-break, print-preview

I know there are many questions and many answers for this. Everyone has different problems with different solutions for different browsers. 
I have tried many solutions from the below URLs. But nothing seems to work.
My output is as follows : 
[image: Output here]
How can I avoid this kind of situation?
I don't want to mess up the table structure. 
This table data are filled up dynamically using handlebars.js. 
Links I have followed:
[Link-1](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks) [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks) [Link-3](https://davidwalsh.name/optimizing-structure-print-css)

`.page-break` is a div class which I have added after each section and that is working fine.
`.Acc_Table` is a table class which is shown in output image starting from SEARS/CBSD row and ending with payment history row. 
How can I solve this? 
Is it possible to close the table before the page break, put in the page break, and reopen the table after the page break?
Or what I wish to display the table on the next page only if it's breaking? 
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if the table or if there is a div that is wrapped around it has the `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline;` CSS property?
I found out that while I was debugging some code for a printing problem that if the table is inline you get this effect. Try to put `display: block` or `display: static`, that works for me